# (wpf) cefsharp - zoom across multiple windows affected by cache

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, cefsharp

i have a couple of instances of ChromoiumWebBrowser on my wpf app and i was trying to adjust the zoom in each one separately, but every time i changed the zoom on one instance, it affected all of the others.

after looking into it, i found that you can set a request context in order to separate the instances like this: `browser.RequestContext = new RequestContext();`.

this made the zoom level for each instance seperate, like i needed. but then i tried setting up a cache folder for them (i want the same folder for all of them) like this: `browser.RequestContext = new RequestContext(new RequestContextSettings { CachePath =  myfolder});`
the zoom went back to being shared.
what is causing that and how can i keep the zoom separated but still have them all in the same cache folder?

Comment: Websites that share the same origin (domain) will also share the same zoom level,  this is the chromium default. See https://superuser.com/questions/677967/chrome-any-way-to-zoom-a-single-page-not-all-pages-in-domain

Comment: You can try creating one RequestContext with the CachePath and then pass that to the constructor overload shown at http://cefsharp.github.io/api/88.2.x/html/M_CefSharp_RequestContext__ctor_1.htm if that doesn't work then you'll have to use different cache paths.